# error handling with chained commands (pipes) in a bash script?

Tags: bash, error-handling

i currently wonder how to do error handling for chained commands. the following is just an example to easy demonstrate my problem:

```
cat file | gzip >/tmp/test
```

if *cat* fails (because for example *file* is missing), *gzip* is still executed and therefore the last stored exit code in *$?* is *0*. *set -e* won't help either in this case.

i wonder what's the best solution for this?

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `$PIPESTATUS` ? It should work for bash.

Comment: i did not even know, that this existed. thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
trap 'echo "ERR caught"' ERR
set -o pipefail
cat file | gzip >/tmp/test
```

The output file will still be created (the creation is done in parallel) and `gzip` will be run, but you can do cleanup. Use the `${PIPESTATUS[@]}` array to see where the error occurred. You can use `$BASH_COMMAND` and `$BASH_LINENO` for additional information regarding the error.

Comment: wow -- that's very cool. i did not know of this possibility. thanks very much!